# Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto, possible values, and what they do

Tags: hibernate, orm, properties, hbm2ddl

I am looking at the Hibernate `hbm2ddl.auto` configuration property and its possible values:

- `validate`
- `update`
- `create`
- `create-drop`

What do all these values do?

The [Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-misc-properties) only talks briefly about `create-drop`, but doesn't say anything about the other values:

> `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`
>
> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the `SessionFactory` is created. With `create-drop`, the database schema will be dropped when the `SessionFactory` is closed explicitly.
>
> **e.g.** `validate` | `update` | `create` | `create-drop`

I found *very* useful explanations in these Stack Overflow questions:

- [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/238421)
- [Schema is not dropped on hbmddl.auto = create.drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752698/238421)

But still nothing in the official documentation.

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Comment: Actually, I linked to this very question. I was looking for *the* official explanation in Hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The link you provided is already the official documentation. So, there's nothing more official and comprehensive as-of today.

So I guess the answer to your question is two-fold:

- either file an enhancement request in the [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH/component/10045) (better with a proposal)
- or [read the corresponding code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/cd590470c0059981537e558a5ff6d114fd24df61/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/SettingsFactory.java#L352)

I know this isn't the perfect answer you dreamt about, but this is actually all you have today.

But the good news is that the project is open-source, so you have all you need to help improve it :-).

Comment: Created an issue, with a tentative proposal: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8789

Answer (score 77):

For `hbm2ddl.auto` property the list of possible options is:

- **validate**: validate that the schema matches, make no changes to the schema of the database, you probably want this for production.
- **update**: update the schema to reflect the entities being persisted
- **create**: creates the schema necessary for your entities, destroying any previous data.
- **create-drop**: create the schema as in **create** above, but also drop the schema at the end of the session. This is great in early development or for testing.

Comment: I tried to flush out your answers, please review my changes to make sure they reflect your original intent and are accurate.

Comment: note that **update** will not create a table that does not exists, while **create** will always truncate any existing data. there is no way to have an automatic way to tell hibernate to **create table only if it does not yet exist**

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I always use update and I never faced "missing table" or something

Answer (score 4):

The documentation has been updated to include this information. Here is a link to the official, current [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl) for this feature.

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto (e.g. none (default value), create-only, drop,
>   create, create-drop, validate, and update)
>
> Setting to perform SchemaManagementTool actions automatically as part of the SessionFactory lifecycle. Valid options are defined by the
>   externalHbm2ddlName value of the Action enum:
>
> ```
> none
>     No action will be performed.
>
> create-only
>     Database creation will be generated.
>
> drop
>     Database dropping will be generated.
>
> create
>     Database dropping will be generated followed by database creation.
>
> create-drop
>     Drop the schema and recreate it on SessionFactory startup. Additionally, drop the schema on SessionFactory shutdown.
>
> validate
>     Validate the database schema
>
> update
>     Update the database schema
> ```