# Hibernate - Cannot create table in postgresql

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to use hibernate framework with eclipse in order to build a simple web application and connect it with PostgreSQL. Here is my code:
[image: My Class]

[image: The persistence xml file]

[image: The test file]

Here is the error:
[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should change property `hibernate.hbmddl.auto` value to `create-drop` or `create` to force hibernate create schema, because `userclass` table is not exists.

More information about `hibernate.hbmddl.auto` is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417561/2055854

Comment: Thank you. Your answer guided me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those whom might encounter the same problem...

I just found the answer for it. Because of the database I am using is postgresql, I had to change the property "hibernate.dialect" in the persistence file. So, the result after the change was:

After that, the table was created!

Thank you.