# hibernate creating duplicate columns automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have started learning HQL recently and tried to create a test application to see how it works.. but when i'm trying to run the project, i see duplicate columns are getting created with NULL value in it.

Here are my project details

I have a table (insurance) with this structure {id,insurance_name,invested_amount,investment_date} which i have create it.

and when i run the application it is creating two additional columns with null values {id,insurance_name,invested_amount,investment_date,INSURANCE_AMOUNT,INSURANCE_DATE } and i dont know from where they were getting created.

hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate4</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
 <mapping resource="insurance.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.roseindia.app.HQL.Insurance" table="INSURANCE">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="insuranceName">
        <column name="INSURANCE_NAME"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="investmentAmount">
        <column name="INSURANCE_AMOUNT"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="investmentDate">
        <column name="INSURANCE_DATE"></column>
    </property> 
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO class:

```
public class Insurance {

private Long id;
private String insuranceName;
private Integer investmentAmount;
private Date investmentDate;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getInsuranceName() {
    return insuranceName;
}
public void setInsuranceName(String insuranceName) {
    this.insuranceName = insuranceName;
}
public Integer getInvestmentAmount() {
    return investmentAmount;
}
public void setInvestmentAmount(Integer investmentAmount) {
    this.investmentAmount = investmentAmount;
}
public Date getInvestmentDate() {
    return investmentDate;
}
public void setInvestmentDate(Date investmentDate) {
    this.investmentDate = investmentDate;
}
}
```

main class:

```
public class SelectClauseExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Session session =null;

    try{

        SessionFactory sessionFactory =new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session= sessionFactory.openSession();

        String SQL_QUERY="select insurance.id, insurance.insuranceName,insurance.investmentAmount,insurance.investmentDate from Insurance insurance";

        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);

        for (java.util.Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();){
            System.out.print("Inside for");
            Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
            System.out.println("ID: "+row[0]);
            System.out.println("Name: "+row[1]);
            System.out.println("Amount: "+row[2]);
            System.out.println("Date: "+row[3]);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){

    }finally{
        session.flush();
        session.close();

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoudd skip property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` from you config file(which means default value and it means no validation, update, creation or dropping takes place when omitting this setting ) or use `validate` if you don't want any update in your DB

please see [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto, possible values and what they do - any official explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077327/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do-any-official-explanat) to know about possible values of 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto'

Comment: Thanks.. it worked.. Also there is issue with my mapping file.. i have mapped incorrect Column names in the mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

With:

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

In this mode you'll don't have any change in your schema, because you have in your file `Mapping file:`

```
       <property name="investmentAmount">
    <column name="INSURANCE_AMOUNT"></column>
</property>
<property name="investmentDate">
    <column name="INSURANCE_DATE"></column>
```

Every time when you run your upplication yoyr schema will be changed.