# Hibernate w/ Derby database: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, derby

I'm receiving this error from Hibernate whenever I try to insert an object into a table in a Derby embedded database:

```
ERROR: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
Aug 30, 2016 2:53:53 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3133)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.ethanrich.dao.CarDAO.insert(CarDAO.java:27)
    at com.ethanrich.finalproject.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2915)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1397)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'ADMIN' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.StatementUtil.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLModStatementNode.verifyTargetTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Code:

Main.class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Model m = new Model();

        ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(new Car(2, "Toyota", "Camry", 2009, dateOf(2012, 7, 23), dateOf(2012, 7, 27), 7600.00, 17500.00, 4));


        for(Vehicle v : vehicles) {
            m.getCarDAO().insert((Car) v);
        }
    }

    public static Date dateOf(int year. int month, int day) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        return new Date(gc.getTimeInMillis());\
    }
}
```

Vehicle.class

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private int year1;
    private String type;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Date start; 
    private Date sold;
    private double cost;
    private double price;

    public Vehicle() {}
    public Vehicle(int id, String type, String make, String model, int year1, Date start, Date sold, double cost, double price) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setType(type);
        this.setMake(make);
        this.setModel(model);
        this.setYear(year1);
        this.setDateStart(start);
        this.setDateSold(sold);
        this.setCost(cost);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }

    // GETTERS

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public String getType() {return type;}
    public String getMake() {return make;}
    public String getModel() {return model;}
    public int getYear() {return year1;}
    public Date getDateStart() {return start;}
    public Date getDateSold() {return sold;}
    public double getCost() {return cost;}
    public double getPrice() {return price;}

    // SETTERS

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}
    public void setMake(String make) {this.make = make;}
    public void setModel(String model) {this.model = model;}
    public void setYear(int year1) {this.year1 = year1;}
    public void setDateStart(Date start) {this.start = start;}
    public void setDateSold(Date sold) {this.sold = sold;}
    public void setCost(double cost) {this.cost = cost;}
    public void setPrice(double price) {this.price = price;}

}
```

Car.class

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private int doors;

    public Car() {
        super();
    }

    public Car(int id, String make, String model, int year1, Date start, Date sold, double cost, double price, int doors) {
        super(id, "CAR", make, model, year1, start, sold, cost, price);
        this.setDoors(doors);
    }

    public int getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }

    public void setDoors(int doors) {
        this.doors = doors;
    }

    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
        return "ID: #" + getId() + " Type: Car, " + getMake() + ", " + getModel() + ", car year is , start inventory date is " +  sdf.format(getDateStart()) + ", date sold " + sdf.format(getDateSold()) + ", dealer’s car cost is $" + getCost() + ", sold price is $" + getPrice() + ", 4 wheels.";
    }
}
```

CarDAO.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;

public class CarDAO {

    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public CarDAO(SessionFactory sf) {
        sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public CarDAO(){}

    public void insert(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void delete(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void update(Car c) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(c);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public Car getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Car c = (Car) session.get(Car.class, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return c;
    }
}
```

Model.class

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.ethanrich.databeans.*;

public class Model {

    private TruckDAO truckDAO;
    private CarDAO carDAO;

    public Model() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Car.class); 

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        carDAO = new CarDAO(sessionFactory);
    }

    public CarDAO getCarDAO() { return carDAO; }
    public void setCarDAO(CarDAO carDAO) { this.carDAO = carDAO;}

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
  <!--  -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:vehicles;create=true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
  <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">ON_CLOSE</property> -->
  <mapping class="com.erisawesome.databeans.Vehicle"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The program simply takes the Car objects in an ArrayList and inserts them into the database.

Comment: The schema name gets defaulted to the username (in your case ADMIN) when a schema isn't specified.

Comment: Ok, how do I fix this then.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following property to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
hibernate.default_schema
```

and give it the schema name which contains your tables. You haven't provided enough information for me to know what that schema name happens to be.

You can look here for explanation of hibernate properties
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html

Comment: Where can I find the schema that contains my tables?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to yours, developing a JAVA / Hibernate / Derby application.

I was able to resolve by changing a `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` Hibernate property. You can read something here ([Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto, possible values, and what they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077327/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)).

Assign the value of `update`, I executed the application once, the schema was created, after that, I commented the instruction.

Comment: Annoyingly in my case when we had to move away from the spring boot yml configuration, the previously defined property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto did not route its way correctly.  Eventually, thanks to your post I changed to hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto and our entities were generated!  I'm still unable to create the spring boot default "SA" schema mind you :-|  I think we are going to have to change the existing data to use "APP".