# The Application is running just fine and also creating the instances of the classes User,Category and product but not creating any tables in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
**This is the pom.xml file**

` <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.4.24.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
     <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
 
  </dependencies> `


**This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file**
    

   ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
       <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
           <property name="connection.driver_class" >com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
           <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycart</property>
           <property name="connection.username" >root</property>
           <property name="connection.password">@DIKDIKHATK</property>
           <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
           <property name="hibernate.hdm2ddl.auto">update</property>
           <property name="show_sql">true</property>
           <property name="format_sql">true</property>
           <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

           <mapping class="com.resumeproject.indicart.entities.User"/>
           <mapping class="com.resumeproject.indicart.entities.Category"/>
           <mapping class="com.resumeproject.indicart.entities.Product"/>
          

               
           
         </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>`


**This is the user entity**

 `package com.resumeproject.indicart.entities;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;


  @Entity
 public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(length=10,name="user_id")
   private int userId;
   @Column(length=100,name="user_name")
   private String userNamme;
   @Column(length=100,name="user_email")
   private String userEmail;
   @Column(length=100,name="user_password")
   private String userPassword;
   @Column(length=12,name="user_phone")
   private String userPhone;
   @Column(length=1500,name="user_pic")
   private String userPic;
   @Column(length=1500,name="user__address")
   private String userAddress;

    public User(int userId, String userNamme, String userEmail, String userPassword,String                 userPhone,String userPic, String userAddress) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userNamme = userNamme;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    this.userPhone = userPhone;
    this.userPic = userPic;
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
}

public User(String userNamme, String userEmail, String userPassword, String userPhone, String    userPic, String userAddress) {
    this.userNamme = userNamme;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    this.userPhone = userPhone;
    this.userPic = userPic;
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
}

public User() {
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserNamme() {
    return userNamme;
}

public void setUserNamme(String userNamme) {
    this.userNamme = userNamme;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public String getUserPhone() {
    return userPhone;
}

public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    this.userPhone = userPhone;
}

public String getUserPic() {
    return userPic;
}

public void setUserPic(String userPic) {
    this.userPic = userPic;
}

public String getUserAddress() {
    return userAddress;
}

public void setUserAddress(String userAddress) {
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "userId=" + userId + ", userNamme=" + userNamme + ", userEmail=" +   userEmail + ", userPassword=" + userPassword + ", userPhone=" + userPhone + ", userPic=" + userPic + ", userAddress=" + userAddress + '}';
}
```

}`

```
**This is my Category entity**
  `package com.resumeproject.indicart.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int categoryId;
private String categoryTitle;
private String categoryDescription;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();

public Category(int categoryId, String categoryTitle, String categoryDescription) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.categoryTitle = categoryTitle;
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
}

public Category() {
}

public Category(String categoryTitle, String categoryDescription,List<Product> products) {
    this.categoryTitle = categoryTitle;
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
    this.products=products;
}


public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryTitle() {
    return categoryTitle;
}

public void setCategoryTitle(String categoryTitle) {
    this.categoryTitle = categoryTitle;
}

public String getCategoryDescription() {
    return categoryDescription;
}

public void setCategoryDescription(String categoryDescription) {
    this.categoryDescription = categoryDescription;
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}
    

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Category{" + "categoryId=" + categoryId + ", categoryTitle=" + categoryTitle + ", categoryDescription=" + categoryDescription + '}';
}
```

}
`
**This is my Product Entity**

```
 `package com.resumeproject.indicart.entities;

  import javax.persistence.Column;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
  import javax.persistence.GenerationType; 
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


  @Entity
  public class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int pId;
  private String pMame;
  @Column(length=3000)
  private String pDesc;
  private String pPhoto;
  private int pPrice;
  private int pDicsount;
  private int pQuantity;
  @ManyToOne
  private Category category;


  public Product() {
  }

  public Product(String pMame, String pDesc, String pPhoto, int pPrice, int pDicsount, int pQuantity,Category category) {
    this.pMame = pMame;
    this.pDesc = pDesc;
    this.pPhoto = pPhoto;
    this.pPrice = pPrice;
    this.pDicsount = pDicsount;
    this.pQuantity = pQuantity;
    this.category=category;
}

public int getpId() {
    return pId;
}

public void setpId(int pId) {
    this.pId = pId;
}

public String getpMame() {
    return pMame;
}

public void setpMame(String pMame) {
    this.pMame = pMame;
}

public String getpDesc() {
    return pDesc;
}

public void setpDesc(String pDesc) {
    this.pDesc = pDesc;
}

public String getpPhoto() {
    return pPhoto;
}

public void setpPhoto(String pPhoto) {
    this.pPhoto = pPhoto;
}

public int getpPrice() {
    return pPrice;
}

public void setpPrice(int pPrice) {
    this.pPrice = pPrice;
}

public int getpDicsount() {
    return pDicsount;
}

public void setpDicsount(int pDicsount) {
    this.pDicsount = pDicsount;
}

public int getpQuantity() {
    return pQuantity;
}

public void setpQuantity(int pQuantity) {
    this.pQuantity = pQuantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" + "pId=" + pId + ", pMame=" + pMame + ", pDesc=" + pDesc + ", pPhoto=" +   pPhoto + ", pPrice=" + pPrice + ", pDicsount=" + pDicsount + ", pQuantity=" + pQuantity + '}';
}
```

}
`

[project directory overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Puys.png)

This is the code for my java application. I tried to change some dependencies and some configuration in the hibernate config file but could not achieve what I wanted to with the database.  Please tell me what am I missing.

I could not find anything on the console as well regarding the Mysql queries.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto, possible values, and what they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077327/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables won't get created by themselves.
You need to create them in your DB unless you are using Spring Boot or something else that can automate table creation?

Comment: even if I use create as the value for the property name hibernate.hdm2ddl.auto in the hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: Yes, but then you need `create` or `create-drop`, in your code you have `update`. If that's true that's probably the issue :). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077327/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Comment: I have'nt found the problem yet but here is something I found on the internet. update: If the value is updated then hibernate first validates whether the table is present in the database or not , if present alters that table as per the changes, if not creates a new one. @Nick, I am using J2EE to develop this project. I am still a beginner

Comment: Have you tried running your application with `update`, `create` or `create-drop` and they don't work as you expect? Check out the article I and Tim posted for you, it explains what each option does.