# Image upload funcationality not working on server

Tags: spring, hibernate

In my application i upload new war file that time previous images not shown in application

my java application i store image in database..

Comment: will you please elaborate

Comment: In my project when i upload new war file on server that time my images not shown..

Comment: need to look at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like in you hibernate configuration you have `hbm2ddl.auto` property set to `create` or `create-drop`.

When set to `create` hibernate will drop the current schema and create a new one on startup. when set to `create-drop`, hibernate will drop the schema at the time of shutdown. so all of your data will be lost.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752698/1629362) answer.

If this is the case then make it `update`. This will update the schema if you made any changes to model but otherwise everything will be as it is.

If this is not the case then you need to show the configuration and code or check log if you are seeing any exceptions.

Comment: My hibernate configuration hbm2ddl.auto set to none. but image not open